# Prove that $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} 1+ (2i \bmod N) = N(N + 1) / 2$ for odd N.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

I was able check by hand that for odd $N$ the $1+ (2i \bmod N)$ produces all values between $1$ and $N$ and for even $N$ there are repeats.

But I've no ideas on how to write a mathematical proof for this. Any hints please?

Edit:

Proof for $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} 1+ 2i = (N+1)^2 -1 = N^2 + 2N$

$\sum_{i = 1}^{N} 1+ 2i = N + N(N+1) = N^2 + 2N$

Comment: I wrote an edit. Does that construe as a proof?

Comment: Do you really  think that you have reached what is asked to you ?

Comment: It's not clear what the "mod N" applies to. Please add some brackets. Is there a "mod N" on the RHS?

Comment: I've added the brackets. There is no "mod N" on the RHS.

Comment: The LHS becomes $$N + \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} k.$$  The rest is routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing
$N=2n+1$,
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{N} 1+ (2i \bmod N) = N(N + 1) / 2
$$
becomes
$$s(n)
=\sum_{i = 1}^{2n+1} 1+ (2i \bmod (2n+1)) 
= (2n+1)(2n+2) / 2
= (2n+1)(n+1)..
$$

Let's get some values.

$s(0)
=1+2\bmod 1
=1
$.

$s(1)
=(1+2\bmod 3)
+(1+4\bmod 3)
+(1+6\bmod 3)
=3+2+1
=6
$.

Doing a simple-minded splitting,
and taking note
(which I did not in my initial attempt)
that the term with
$i=2n+1$ is $1$,

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{i = 1}^{2n+1} 1+ (2i \bmod (2n+1))\\ 
&=2n+1+\sum_{i = 1}^{2n+1} (2i \bmod (2n+1))\\ 
&=2n+1+\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(2i \bmod (2n+1))+\sum_{i = n+1}^{2n} (2i \bmod (2n+1))+(2(2n+1)\bmod (2n+1))\\
&=2n+1+\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(2i)+\sum_{i = n+1}^{2n} (2i -(2n+1))\\
&=2n+1+2\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(i)+\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (2(i+n) -(2n+1))\\
&=2n+1+n(n+1)+\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (2i-1)\\
&=2n+1+n(n+1)+n(n+1)-n\\
&=n+1+2n(n+1)\\
&=(2n+1)(n+1)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I agree with the transformation giving $s(n)$. But beyond, there is a shortcut: function $i \to 2i \ \operatorname{mod} (2n+1)$ is a bijection inside the set of integers $[1,2n]$ ; the summation of these integers gives at once $n(2n+1)$ to which one has to add $\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} 1 = 2n+1$

Comment: Not surprised that there is a better way. I just plodded on doing the minimal amount of thinking (like being in an improv scene).

Comment: I like the comparison with an improv scene. I have sometimes the same attitude. One of my former teachers said "here, it's good to follow the the trotting donkey"